# Which date and time will insert into SQL Server Database if I wrote in sql query as Getdate() for createDate field?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

If I published my Asp.Net solution on a server and server date time is correct.

Now, When any user access that URL from LAN network on another PC and that PC date time is not correct.

In that case if I write 
`Insert Into tblComp(1,'XYZ','Jam',GETDATE())` in my query.Then which date time will be inserted.Server or PC(which have accessing that URL)

```
tblComp structure
********************
id int,
SName varchar(50),
SAdd varchar(50),
CreateDate Datetime
*********************
```

Comment: run `select getdate()` in db and whatever result will come the same pattern will  insert in your table `getdate()` gives us current machine time

Comment: Server date and time...

Comment: sql server date time

Comment: `GetDate` returns the sever's date and time.

Answer (score 2):

The query executes on the database server, the database server will provide its current date and time.

Please note that this date and time will be in whatever time zone the database server is in as well.

From [the documentation of `GETDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx):

> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server is running.

If, on the other hand, you actually want the local date and time of the client, you will have to provide that through a parameter. On an ASP.NET site, this is not all that easy because the "client code" will the ASP.NET application, running on the web server, so instead of the date and time of the database server you would effectively use the date and time of the web server.

To actually get the client date and time (that is, the local date and time of the computer running the web browser that is browsing the site), you would probably have to resort to javascript, though I'm completely unfamiliar with how you would do that.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` for `C#` or `date()` for `javascript`,when sent as an parameter to server, might help if clients date and time should be used.

Comment: Yes, but how you would actually structure the javascript in the browser and get that sent back to the web server I don't know, hence I won't write more on that part of the answer.